# Java math library with entropy calculation function

Tags: library, java

I am looking for an open source Java math/linear algebra library with a function to calculate entropy of 2D arrays. 
The algorithm should be able to calculate entropy of continuous values. Nice to have would be an algorithm similar to the one used by Octave/Matlab.